# Classic ASP with MySQL UNION

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have a table of testimonials. Some are marked as internal, some as external. What I want to do is produce a recordset that outputs all the internal ones followed by 5 of the external ones, and these are randomly ordered. I have built the SQL successfully directly in my database, and it returns exactly what I want it to. It looks like this:

```
(SELECT tText, tName FROM tblTestimonials WHERE tExternal = 0 ORDER BY RAND())
UNION
(SELECT tText, tName FROM tblTestimonials WHERE tExternal = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)
```

However when I plugged this into my Classic ASP page, which was working completely fine with a simple non-UNION SQL statement of a very similar nature, it falls over when I try and output tText. It is fine with tName (and if I add it in to the SELECT statement, it's happy with outputting tExternal too).

I get this error:

> error '80020009'
>   Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

`tName` (which works) is a nullable `varchar(500)`

`tText` (which errors) is a nullable `varchar(8000)`

It looks as if the UNION is doing something to the data type of the larger text field. The only way I have been able to make it work is by using:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(tText, CHAR(500)) AS tText, tName FROM tblTestimonials WHERE tExternal = 0 ORDER BY RAND())
UNION
(SELECT CONVERT(tText, CHAR(500)) AS tText, tName FROM tblTestimonials WHERE tExternal = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)
```

But then I end up losing a lot of data. I can only output incomplete reviews.

If anyone has any experience with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Out of interest what driver are you using to connect?  I've never used any sort of OLEDB driver with MySQL, MyODBC is what most applications use, and I've never had any problems with union queries

Comment: @John I'm using: MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver

Comment: Instead of Char(500), what if you use  CHAR_LENGTH(tText)? Not sure if it'll work as the lengths will be different in different records but may be worth trying.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `LIMIT 5` from the second half of your query?

Comment: @Swagata that isn't valid SQL, you can't have different rows with different data lengths like that

Comment: @RobertSimpson that did allow the tText field to display. but removes the reason for using the union in the first place. I can achieve the same result from: `SELECT tText, tName FROM tblTestimonials ORDER BY tExternal, RAND()` - I was trying to limit the number of rows of external testimonials I brought back, as there can be lots. But this will certainly do for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before.

You'll see that it works magically if you use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

The difference between them is `UNION` deduplicates the rows (with a temporary table on the fly), `UNION ALL` does not. Since you don't need deduplication, using Union All should be OK.

Why it works? I can only speculate.

During (or after) deduplication process the data may be corrupted and become something cannot be handled on the client side (*the OLEDB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL)* sitting between ASP and MySQL ODBC driver).

---

[UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked a treat, I never would've thought to try that!

Comment: @VampiricMonkey You're welcolme. BTW You also have not tried `CONVERT(tText, CHAR)` which also works loseless.

Comment: I had already tried that one and it didn't work for me. But the Union All works perfectly, so my problem is solved.